# trying to build a basic basic game engine

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, game-engine, drawimage

I'm trying to teach myself about what goes into a game engine by building my own. when I said basic basic game engine, that was no typo. all I have so far is a simple text loader, and I'm working on a single image loader. I can not get my images to appear in the canvas even with and .onload = function style technique. In fact, I always have problems with images loading, I, just for shits and giggles, made a video loader that loaded four short videos, made and attached video tags and the divs that held them, and STILL, images drive me nut guys and girls! wtf! any help, but more importantly insight would be invaluable and helpful to a rookie at trying to understand as opposed to copying without understanding. Thanks in advance.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

function drawText(context, pxSize, fontStyle, color, text, x, y){
  context.font = pxSize + 'px ' + fontStyle;
  context.fillStyle = color;
  context.fillText(text, x, y);
}

function drawHero(src, sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight, x, y, height, width){ 

  var hero = {
    image: new Image(),
    src: src,
    sourceX: sourceX,
    sourceY: sourceY,
    sourceWidth: sourceWidth + 'px',
    sourceHeight: sourceHeight + 'px',
    x: x,
    y: y,
    width: width + 'px',
    height: height + 'px'
  };

  hero.image.onload = function(){

   context.drawImage(hero.image, hero.sourceX, hero.sourceY, hero.sourceWidth, 

hero.sourceHeight, hero.x, hero.y, hero.width, hero.height);
  }
  hero.image.src = src;
}


drawHero("sonic.png" , "sonic1", 0, 0, 85, 119, 10, 10, 85, 119);
```

Comment: I believe this question may be better suited for http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

You defined `hero.width` and `hero.height` to be a string and that causes an error because `context.drawImage` needs a number for height and width.

Take away the `width: width + "px"` and `height: height + "px"` and replace it with `width: width` and `height: height`.

EDIT: just realized you did the same to `hero.sourceWidth` and `hero.sourceHeight`.

EDIT 2: just realized that you passed in 10 parameters to `drawHero` when it only takes in 9. You should remove `"sonic1"`.

EDIT 3: You ordered the parameters to `context.drawImage` wrong too.
You might want to read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage .
Use this:
`context.drawImage(hero.image, hero.x, hero.y, hero.width, hero.height, hero.sourceX, hero.sourceY, hero.sourceWidth, hero.sourceHeight);`

Good luck with your game engine!

Comment: Sorry, I've been swamped with work, but I just wanted to say thank you for your help, we gotta stick together and make sure to show appreciation, your suggestion worked like a charm, now I'm see if I can understand GameAlchemist's post for more images, I'm trying to get a smooth, easy loading system for tiles and especially orthographic map, which blows my mind. I'm a huge civ fan, but I busted a brain trying to make it, why did I decide to try this again? anyway big ups for the help.

Answer (score 1):

To have your images, and more generally your resources, loaded right, have a separate function to create the resources, and have a 'start' function that launches the engines once every resource is loaded.

```
var resourceCount = 0;
function loadResource(type, src) {
    if (type == Image) {
       resourceCount++;
       var newImage = new Image();
       newImage.onload = resourceLoaded;
       // you might want to handle errors to ease debugging.
       // newImage.onerror = ...
       newImage.src = src;
       return newImage;
    }
    // ... some other code for your text / sound / ... ressources
}

function resourceLoaded(loadedEvt) {
   resourceCount--;
   if (resourceCount == 0) startEngine();
}

// use with :
var heroImage = loadResource(Image, 'hero.png');
```

Comment: I just got to get around to seeing this, I believe in sharing, so I've been watching this video JavaScript the weird parts, take on Crawford, and this guy knows his stuff, anyway, thank you, thank you, thank you, for the help. I haven't tried it, but I'm working through it now so I can understand instead of just copying, I get what your doing, but not in depth, that way I can reproduce it myself, For example, I'm trying to use a JSON object to hold the picture srcs, names and indexes so I can make a tile map,

Comment: I'm a huge civ fan, and I would love to build something similar. Anyway, thank you for the help! PS I saw hear something about vampires or something, if I have lots of question, how do I not become one of those?